# Ext JS : How to find a record in a Grid with multiple column values

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS grid which has 15 items on each page. Individual items can be searched using Ext.getCmp('id').store.data.items[0];

But I want a generic functions which can search for a particular record on any page based on number of columns value which I supply.

Also when it has found the record I need to click on the checkbox(in the first column) of the corresponding row

I am new bee to ExtJS
[View ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvFFh.png)
[View Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIwck.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are loking for `Ext.data.Store` [find()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-find) and [findBy()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findBy) methods.

[This fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14da) illustrate how you can use it.

Comment: When i am trying to use find() like : Ext.getCmp('TransactionDetailsLV').getStore().find('TransactionNumber','1000000004-2158') it is returning -1, even when this value is present in the grid.

Comment: @DevX Can you share part of your code related to the grid and its store?

Comment: Sergey : I am trying to automate a ExtJS Website using javascript, so i don't have acess to code base.

Comment: @DevX Well, than Im not sure why its return -1. Try to use `findBy` and check all records its loop through.

Comment: I tried to debug by firebug.. it returned store and then checked its data property -> Items -> data -> columns..

Comment: I have the screen shot if it will of some help

Comment: As I see on your screenshot that TransactionNumber column is actually a link (or just colored as blue?) so I guess its using some sort of custom renderer. When you use `find('TransactionNumber','10000000‌​04-2158')` are you sure that store record contain `TransactionNumber` field and its value exactly `10000000‌​04-2158`?
P.S. Why you show debuger DOM tab? ExtJS Store not associated with DOM.

Comment: Yes it has first record as this number. Also If try to search Date column it is returning -1 again.

Comment: How you tryin to search on date column? If `find('myDateColumnName','01\01\2016')` I guess its wrong also because most likely actual record value for date field is hex.

Comment: Yes I did Ext.getCmp('PolicyDetailTransactions:PolicyDetailJournalScreen:TransactionDetailsLV').getStore().find('Date','22/01/2016')
It is again returning -1

Comment: I think that a problem is that you're trying to search for record by displayed values (from DOM?) and its not match actual record data.

Comment: I update my fiddle, check its `name` column configuration. Display value is changed but we still have to `find('name', 'Lisa')`.

Comment: Yes even I tried on you fiddle it is working. I have attached one more screen shot where the value is exactly the same

Comment: Again, on your screenshot DOM tab is opened, its Document Object Model wich is representation of page HTML, while ExtJS Store is an JS object and has nothing in common with DOM.